# Inserting multiple records in to a table using a sing record by incrementing the Pk

Tags: oracle

I have to insert a million record in to a table using a single existing record, just by incrementing the PK. Is there a simple way to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there's a simple way. Here's a simple example of generating a million rows and cross joining it to a single row from an existing table (in this case, dual):

```
WITH dummy AS (SELECT LEVEL lvl
               FROM   dual
               CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 1000)
SELECT sd.col1, -- replace with your column list that you want to insert into the table
       ROWNUM pk -- replace with the sequence used to generate the pk, e.g.:   pk_seq.nextval
FROM   (SELECT 'abc' col1 FROM dual) sd -- replace with your 1 row selected from your table
       CROSS JOIN dummy
       CROSS JOIN dummy;

COL1         PK
---- ----------
abc           1
abc           2
abc           3
abc           4
...
```

So your insert statement would look something like:

```
insert into your_table (pk_col, col1, col2, col3, ...)
WITH dummy AS (SELECT LEVEL lvl
               FROM   dual
               CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 1000)
SELECT your_table_pk_seq.nextval pk_col,
       yt.col1,
       yt.col2,
       yt.col3,
       ...
FROM   your_table yt
       CROSS JOIN dummy
       CROSS JOIN dummy;
```

This is assuming you have a sequence that generates the primary key column values, which of course you have... right?!

It's an odd requirement, though - unless you're using it to create test data? In which case, I hope you're changing some of the other columns to create more realistic data.

Comment: N.B. you could use a single dummy subquery with the level <= 1000000, but it can be faster to generate a smaller number of rows and cross join it.

Comment: i am new to pl sql so can you kindly explain me the query execution?

Comment: This isn't PL/SQL, this is plain SQL. If you're not familiar with SQL, I highly recommend you read about [SQL in the concepts manual](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e40540/sqllangu.htm#CNCPT1734). The query I have given you consists of a subquery called "dummy" (which is defined in the WITH clause - aka subquery factoring aka (in other database platforms) Common Table Expressions (CTE) - which is cross joined to itself (i.e. each row in the subquery is joined to all rows in the subquery so you end up with 1000 x 1000 rows), before cross joining it back to your table.

Comment: If you want to see what individual bits of a query are doing, you can always break the query down. E.g. you could run the sql creating the dummy subquery by itself - i.e. `with dummy as (..) select * from dummy;`. You could then see what happens when you cross join it to itself - i.e. `with dummy as (...) select * from dummy cross join dummy;` and so on.